# Pivoting a table with results diveded by USERNAME

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I'll try to make it as simple as I can:

I have a table that registers whatever a USER (employee) is doing (it can be starting his job, registering new products, delivering products and ending his job). The most common scenario is when the user starts his job, do whatever he needs to do during the day, and then ends his job on the same day he started, so these are the info that matter to me now (start and end).

This query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
DATEPART(DAY,TimeStamp) [Day],
DATEPART(MONTH,TimeStamp) [Month],
DATEPART(YEAR,TimeStamp) [Year],
login [USER],
CASE WHEN TipoOcorrencia = 'IniciarDia'     THEN 'YES' END [Started],
CASE WHEN TipoOcorrencia = 'FinalizacaoDia' THEN 'YES' END [Ended]
FROM CHAMADO ch
WHERE
    TimeStamp >= '20151001'
    AND TipoOcorrencia = 'IniciarDia' OR TipoOcorrencia = 'FinalizacaoDia'
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(DAY,TimeStamp),
    DATEPART(MONTH,TimeStamp),
    DATEPART(YEAR,TimeStamp),
    login,
    TipoOcorrencia
ORDER BY [USER], [Year],[Month],[Day]
```

returns something like this (but with more users):

[image: results without pivot]

You can see that this user has Started and Ended his job day on the same date in three different days (10/7, 10/8 and 10/9).

By correctly using **PIVOT** I believe that is possible to obtain the following expected result: 
[image: expected result with pivot]

Obviously my problem is that I, despite trying really hard, could not make **PIVOT** work. And I need help...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wrap your case statements in max and get rid of group by on tipocorrencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not positive but I believe this will work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
DATEPART(DAY,TimeStamp) [Day],
DATEPART(MONTH,TimeStamp) [Month],
DATEPART(YEAR,TimeStamp) [Year],
login [USER],
--Modified these two lines
max(CASE WHEN TipoOcorrencia = 'IniciarDia'     THEN 'YES' END) [Started], 
max(CASE WHEN TipoOcorrencia = 'FinalizacaoDia' THEN 'YES' END) [Ended]
--End modification
FROM CHAMADO ch
WHERE
    TimeStamp >= '20151001'
    AND TipoOcorrencia = 'IniciarDia' OR TipoOcorrencia = 'FinalizacaoDia'
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(DAY,TimeStamp),
    DATEPART(MONTH,TimeStamp),
    DATEPART(YEAR,TimeStamp),
    login--,
    --commented out this next one and remove comma above.
    --TipoOcorrencia
ORDER BY [USER], [Year],[Month],[Day]
```

Why does this work?  tipoOcorrencia is being grouped by, and you needed to because of your case statement, but if you max the value you can eliminate the group by causing the multiple lines to be combined.

An alternative approach is to treat this as a table itself and just get the max values after the fact...  but this is slower and less clean in my opinion as it resolves the symptom, not the problem.

```
with cte as (SELECT DISTINCT
DATEPART(DAY,TimeStamp) [Day],
DATEPART(MONTH,TimeStamp) [Month],
DATEPART(YEAR,TimeStamp) [Year],
login [USER],
CASE WHEN TipoOcorrencia = 'IniciarDia'     THEN 'YES' END [Started],
CASE WHEN TipoOcorrencia = 'FinalizacaoDia' THEN 'YES' END [Ended]
FROM CHAMADO ch
WHERE
    TimeStamp >= '20151001'
    AND TipoOcorrencia = 'IniciarDia' OR TipoOcorrencia = 'FinalizacaoDia'
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(DAY,TimeStamp),
    DATEPART(MONTH,TimeStamp),
    DATEPART(YEAR,TimeStamp),
    login,
    TipoOcorrencia)

Select 
[Day],[Month],[Year],
login , Max([Started]), max([Ended])
 from cte
GROUP BY  [Day],[Month],[Year],
login
ORDER BY [USER], [Year],[Month],[Day]
```

Comment: Your first approach solved the problem. The second returned `Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 43
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.`

Comment: ah had to move the order by to the query on the cte.

Comment: sorry my stupidity, but I still cannot fully understand why it works, and how tipoOcorrencia being grouped by was causing half the problem. Would you care to try to explain it to me again? Tks!

Comment: The group by isn't grouping on yes, no... it's grouping on IniciarDia FinalizacaoDia and ALL other values of TIpoOcorrencia. It's these other values which were causing additional records to appear.    By using a max statement, we exclude all the other values because we eliminate the group by.  Take your original query and add tipo)Correncia to the select.  You may be able to understand why better with it displayed.  Yet another alternative would be to use a where clause to limit to just the two values in your case statement. or add a having

Answer (score 1):

One way this could potentially work is by changing up your CASE statements a little bit.  Also, please modify your provided data to show what you would expect to see if someone did not start and end their work on the same day.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
DATEPART(DAY,TimeStamp) [Day],
DATEPART(MONTH,TimeStamp) [Month],
DATEPART(YEAR,TimeStamp) [Year],
login [USER],
MAX(CASE WHEN TipoOcorrencia = 'IniciarDia' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Started],
MAX(CASE WHEN TipoOcorrencia = 'FinalizacaoDia' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Ended]
FROM CHAMADO ch
WHERE
    TimeStamp >= '20151001'
    AND TipoOcorrencia = 'IniciarDia' OR TipoOcorrencia = 'FinalizacaoDia'
GROUP BY
 DATEPART(DAY,TimeStamp),
DATEPART(MONTH,TimeStamp),
DATEPART(YEAR,TimeStamp),
login
ORDER BY [USER], [Year],[Month],[Day]
```

Also, as a side note, it is a best practice with SQL coding to include an ELSE statement in your CASE code.

Comment: IDK why but sql server is returning `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
Incorrect syntax near ','.`

Comment: It's missing end ) for each of the max aggregates after the END of each case. `MAX(CASE WHEN TipoOcorrencia = 'IniciarDia' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END^^^)^^^AS [Started],`